# Creating Azure subscription with Variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that is supposed to create a Azure subscription, to provide values I have set up a variable calld `serviceConnection`:

```
jobs:
  - job: Variables
    displayName: 'Variables'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Get Json values and set output variables'
      name: setOutput
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |

          serviceConnection=$(cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test/*.json | jq -r '.test.serviceConnection')
        
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceConnection;isoutput=true]$serviceConnection"

  - job: CreateSubscription
    displayName: 'Create Subscription to Azure'
    dependsOn: Variables
    variables:
    - name: serviceConnection
      value: $[ dependencies.Variables.outputs['setOutput.serviceConnection'] ]

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: CreateSubscriptionCli
      displayName: 'Create a subscription'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
```

But when i start the pipeline i get this error:

`"The pipeline is not valid. Job CreateSubscription: Step CreateSubscription input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection $(serviceConnection) which could not be found.`

when i print out the variable it shows the value as intended.

using syntax:

`${{ parameters.serviceConnection}}`

i get similar error but with

`$[ dependencies.Variables.outputs['setOutput.serviceConnection'] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The pipeline is not valid. Job CreateSubscription: Step CreateSubscription input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection $(serviceConnection) which could not be found.

From the YAML sample, you are using the cross-jobs variable to pass the service connection value.

The variable value will be set at runtime. But the Azure CLI task will read the azureSubscription Service connection value at compile time.

In this case, the variable `$(serviceConnection)` in Azure CLI task will not able to get value at compile time and show the error above.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc about [cross-jobs variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage).

For a workaround, you can split the pipeline to two. One is used to get the service connection value in Json file. And then the first pipeline can trigger the second pipeline and pass the value to the second pipeline to run Azure CLI task.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that I understand at all what you are trying to do...but: The input "azureSubscription" for the `AzureCLI@2` task, is a well-defined input which needs to reference an existing Azure DevOps Service Connection.

Comment: Its a cutdown version of the full code to simplify the question where i left wrong variable, `serviceConnection` is the correct one. Name of the service connection is stated in the json file. I wanted the pipeline to use the value from json so i can provide needed values from it.
To me it looks like pipeline does not read the value of the variable, but i might be wrong.

Comment: now your code just looks wrong. I'm not sure if this is a copy and paste mistake or not. Your first line in bash is assigning one variable and the next line is using a different one.

Comment: correct its a copy-paste mistake, fixed